# Does the facebook API allow you to tag pictures?

Tags: facebook

As the title states, does the facebook API allow developers to write an app that will automatically tag pictures?  Or is that outside of the scope?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Graph API to tag users in Pictures https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

Remember that under Facebook's policies, your app must not encourage in-authentic use of this behaviour. If your app is found to be breaking these rules, it may be disabled.